# Answer always coming back as 'incorrect' and not calling on next function

Tags: javascript

I'm a very novice high school student and have been trying very hard to get this code to work but just cannot.  It is supposed to be an area game where an image is shown and the user inputs an answer and presses the check button, where the javascript should output if the answer was correct/incorrect and a point is added to the score and subsequently, then the next question is displayed.  However, whenever I input the correct answer to the first question, the javascript outputs that the answer to the question is incorrect and then does not load the next question.  I know my code is long and probably doesn't make much sense but any help would be appreciated to get this game working.

```js
var number1;
var number2;
var response;
var calcanswer;
var score = 0;
score.innerHTML = "SCORE: " + score;

areaquestion1();
areaquestion2();
areaquestion3();
areaquestion4();
areaquestion5();
areaquestion6();
areaquestion7();
areaquestion8();
areaquestion9();
areaquestion10();

function areaquestion1() {
    var imageBlock = document.createElement("img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("id", "img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("src", "Images/2_1.png");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("width", "700");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("height", "400");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("alt", "2_1");
    document.getElementById('img').appendChild(imageBlock); 
    number1 = 2
    number2 = 1
    calcanswer = (number1*number2);
    var question = document.getElementById("question");
    question.innerHTML = "What is the area of this lego brick?";  
    document.getElementById("somethingelse")
}

function areaquestion2() {
    var imageBlock = document.createElement("img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("id", "img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("src", "Images/4_2.png");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("width", "700");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("height", "400");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("alt", "4_2");
    document.getElementById('img').appendChild(imageBlock); 
    number1 = 4
    number2 = 2
    calcanswer = (number1*number2);
    var question = document.getElementById("question");
    question.innerHTML = "What is the area of this lego brick?";  
    document.getElementById("somethingelse")
}

function areaquestion3() {
    var imageBlock = document.createElement("img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("id", "img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("src", "Images/3_2.png");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("width", "700");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("height", "400");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("alt", "3_2");
    document.getElementById('img').appendChild(imageBlock); 
    number1 = 3
    number2 = 2
    calcanswer = (number1*number2);
    var question = document.getElementById("question");
    question.innerHTML = "What is the area of this lego brick?";  
    document.getElementById("somethingelse")
}

function areaquestion4() {
    var imageBlock = document.createElement("img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("id", "img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("src", "Images/4_3.png");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("width", "700");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("height", "400");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("alt", "4_3");
    document.getElementById('img').appendChild(imageBlock); 
    number1 = 4
    number2 = 3
    calcanswer = (number1*number2);
    var question = document.getElementById("question");
    question.innerHTML = "What is the area of this lego brick?";  
    document.getElementById("somethingelse")
}

function areaquestion5() {
    var imageBlock = document.createElement("img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("id", "img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("src", "Images/6_1.png");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("width", "700");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("height", "400");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("alt", "6_1");
    document.getElementById('img').appendChild(imageBlock); 
    number1 = 6
    number2 = 1
    calcanswer = (number1*number2);
    var question = document.getElementById("question");
    question.innerHTML = "What is the area of this lego brick?";  
    document.getElementById("somethingelse")
}

function areaquestion6() {
    var imageBlock = document.createElement("img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("id", "img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("src", "Images/2_2.png");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("width", "700");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("height", "400");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("alt", "2_2");
    document.getElementById('img').appendChild(imageBlock); 
    number1 = 2
    number2 = 2
    calcanswer = (number1*number2);
    var question = document.getElementById("question");
    question.innerHTML = "What is the area of this lego brick?";  
    document.getElementById("somethingelse")
}

function areaquestion7() {
    var imageBlock = document.createElement("img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("id", "img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("src", "Images/4_1.png");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("width", "700");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("height", "400");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("alt", "4_1");
    document.getElementById('img').appendChild(imageBlock); 
    number1 = 4
    number2 = 1
    calcanswer = (number1*number2);
    var question = document.getElementById("question");
    question.innerHTML = "What is the area of this lego brick?";  
    document.getElementById("somethingelse")
}

function areaquestion8() {
    var imageBlock = document.createElement("img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("id", "img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("src", "Images/6_4.png");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("width", "700");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("height", "400");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("alt", "6_4");
    document.getElementById('img').appendChild(imageBlock); 
    number1 = 6
    number2 = 4
    calcanswer = (number1*number2);
    var question = document.getElementById("question");
    question.innerHTML = "What is the area of this lego brick?";  
    document.getElementById("somethingelse")
}

function areaquestion9() {
    var imageBlock = document.createElement("img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("id", "img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("src", "Images/6_2.png");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("width", "700");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("height", "400");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("alt", "6_2");
    document.getElementById('img').appendChild(imageBlock); 
    number1 = 6
    number2 = 2
    calcanswer = (number1*number2);
    var question = document.getElementById("question");
    question.innerHTML = "What is the area of this lego brick?";  
    document.getElementById("somethingelse")
}

function areaquestion10() {
    var imageBlock = document.createElement("img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("id", "img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("src", "Images/4_3.png");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("width", "700");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("height", "400");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("alt", "4_3");
    document.getElementById('img').appendChild(imageBlock); 
    number1 = 4
    number2 = 3
    calcanswer = (number1*number2);
    var question = document.getElementById("question");
    question.innerHTML = "What is the area of this lego brick?";  
    document.getElementById("somethingelse")
}

function check() {
    var statusDiv = document.getElementById("status");
    response==document.getElementById("answer").value;
    document.getElementById("somethingelse")
    if (response==calcanswer)
    {
        statusDiv.innerHTML="Very good!";
        score ++;
        document.getElementById("score").textContent = score
        document.getElementById("answer").value = "";
    }
    else {
    if(response != calcanswer)
        statusDiv.innerHTML="Incorrect";

        
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Lego Area Play</title>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/gridtest.css">
    <script src="JavaScript/Play.js"></script>
  </head>
<body onload="areaquestion1()";>
  
  <div class="header">
    <h1>LEGO AREA</h1>
    <p>Calculating <b>area</b> with Emmet.</p>
    <div id="scorelabel"><label>SCORE:</label></div>
    <div id="score" class="score"></div>
  </div>


<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#fff;">
      <div id="question"></div>
      <div id="img"></div>
      <div id="status"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#fff;">
        <div id ="prompt"></div>
        <label>Area = </label>
        <input type="text" id="answer" placeholder="Answer"/>
        <label>Units<sup>2</sup></label>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#fff;">
        <input id="somethingelse" type="button" value="CHECK!" onclick="check()">
        <div class="practice"> <a href="Practice.html"><img src="Images/legoBlue2.png" id="practicebtn" alt="lego button for practice page" width=350px height=140px></a></div>
        <div class="menu"> <a href="LegoWelcome.html"><img src="Images/menured.png" id="menubtn" alt = "lego button for menu page" width=350px height=140px></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The second line of the check function has a double equal sign. I think that's the problem.

```
response==document.getElementById("answer").value;
```

It should be:

```
response=document.getElementById("answer").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I shortened your code a little bit. How about the following:

**JavaScript:**

```
var number1;
var number2;
var response;
var calcanswer;
var score = 0;
var i = 0;

function areaquestion(i) {
    var questions = [
        ["Images/2_1.png", "2_1", 2, 1, "What is the area of this lego brick?"],
        ["Images/4_2.png", "4_2", 4, 2, "What is the area of this lego brick?"],
        ["Images/3_2.png", "3_2", 3, 2, "What is the area of this lego brick?"],
        ["Images/4_3.png", "4_3", 4, 3, "What is the area of this lego brick?"],
        ["Images/6_1.png", "6_1", 6, 1, "What is the area of this lego brick?"],
        ["Images/2_2.png", "2_2", 2, 2, "What is the area of this lego brick?"],
        ["Images/4_1.png", "4_1", 4, 1, "What is the area of this lego brick?"],
        ["Images/6_4.png", "6_4", 6, 4, "What is the area of this lego brick?"],
        ["Images/6_2.png", "6_2", 6, 2, "What is the area of this lego brick?"],
        ["Images/4_3.png", "4_3", 4, 3, "What is the area of this lego brick?"],
    ]

    var imageBlock = document.createElement("img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("id", "img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("src", questions[i][0]);
    imageBlock.setAttribute("width", "700");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("height", "400");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("alt", questions[i][1]);
    document.getElementById('img').innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('img').appendChild(imageBlock); 
    number1 = questions[i][2]
    number2 = questions[i][3]
    calcanswer = (number1*number2);
    var question = document.getElementById("question");
    question.innerHTML = questions[i][4];  
}

areaquestion(i)

function check() {
    var statusDiv = document.getElementById("status");
    response=document.getElementById("answer").value;
    if (response==calcanswer)
    {
        statusDiv.innerHTML="Very good!";
        score ++;
        document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score
        document.getElementById("answer").value = "";
    }
    else if(response != calcanswer)
        statusDiv.innerHTML="Incorrect";

    if (i < 9) {
        i++
        areaquestion(i)
    }

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Lego Area Play</title>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/gridtest.css">
    <script src="JavaScript/Play.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
    <h1>LEGO AREA</h1>
    <p>Calculating <b>area</b> with Emmet.</p>
    <div id="scorelabel"><label>SCORE:</label></div>
    <div id="score" class="score"></div>
</div>


<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column" style="background-color:#fff;">
            <div id="question"></div>
            <div id="img"></div>
            <div id="status"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="column" style="background-color:#fff;">
            <div id ="prompt"></div>
            <label>Area = </label>
            <input type="text" id="answer" placeholder="Answer"/>
            <label>Units<sup>2</sup></label>
        </div>
        <div class="column" style="background-color:#fff;">
            <input id="somethingelse" type="button" value="CHECK!" onclick="check()">
            <div class="practice"> <a href="Practice.html"><img src="Images/legoBlue2.png" id="practicebtn" alt="lego button for practice page" width=350px height=140px></a></div>
            <div class="menu"> <a href="LegoWelcome.html"><img src="Images/menured.png" id="menubtn" alt = "lego button for menu page" width=350px height=140px></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```